# A line segment is drawn from one centroid of a triangle to the centroid of another triangle. Is the line parallel to their bases?

Tags: geometry

[image: Two triangles with 2 center points]

Given that $G$ and $G'$ are the centroids of triangles $ABC$ and $ACD$, respectively, and that $|GG'|=12$ cm, what is the value of $|BD|$?

Figure is not to scale, so $C$ may or may not be the middle point of $BD$.

I can find the answer ($36$ cm) by assuming that $GG'$ is parallel to $BD$. After that, it is a matter of setting up the similarity ratios to find $BD$.

I wanted to know if I'm correct in my assumption that these two lines are parallel? If yes, can you show me how?

Comment: Which center of the triangle are you referring to? There are several. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_center

Comment: I didn't know. I'll clarify and edit my question.Thanks

Comment: For centroids, $G' - G = (A+D+C)/3 - (A+C+B)/3 = (D-B)/3$

Comment: Yes, It is centroid, where the 3 medians intersect

Comment: As suggested by @achillehui's comment, since centroid of a triangle XYZ in vector notation is given by $\frac{\vec{X} + \vec{Y} + \vec{Z}}{3}, $ you can find $\vec{GG'} = \vec{G'} - \vec{G} = (\frac{\vec{D} - \vec{B}}{3})$, so $GG'$ is parallel to $DB$ and one-third of it in length.

Comment: thanks got it. I'm grateful